# Correct way to update model variable inside UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I'm developing an application with `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`. Everything works like a charm, in fact I've got my `collectionView` updated automatically when I add a new model. However I'm unable to see updated cell when I update one of my present elements.

Here's an example:

I've got this model

```
final class Contact: Hashable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
        hasher.combine(name)
    }
    static func == (lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool {
        
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
}
```

which populates my `UICollectionView`. If I try to update for example its name on `didSelectItem`, and then call my function which analyze differences with `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot`, it doesn't update my `UICollectionView`. If I add another `Contact` on didSelect (just for test), my `UICollectionView` got updated perfectly as I want.

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved on my own. I tried to change class declaration to `struct` instead of `final class`. I don't really know why, but it seems that in array of items declared as `Class`, snapshot check if reference is the same, but not its content. So it doesn't update view when I update any variable, even if I added them to either `hash required function` and `equatable required function`